# Office.js: Add multiple rows on Excel using Excel.Range class

Tags: javascript, excel, office-js

I want to add multiple rows at a time to table on Excel. Right now we are adding using for loop.

```
 await Excel.run(async (ctx: Excel.RequestContext) => {
        sheet = ctx.workbook.worksheets.getItem('sheetName');
        table = ctx.workbook.tables.getItem('tableName');
        await ctx.sync();

        for (let i: number = 0; i < addRowCount; i++) {
          table.rows.add();
        }
}
```

Is there API on Office js which allow to insert multiple rows at a time?. I was exploring Excel.Range class. but did not find any helpful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Beginning with Excel.js 1.4, you can use the same add method to add multiple rows. See [TableRowCollection.add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/excel/excel.tablerowcollection?view=excel-js-preview#add-index--values-).

Comment: No code example :(